# laravel query builder multiple left join with multiple where clause condition from different tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables

```
transactions
----------------
id
cash_id
credit_id

cash
---------------
-id 
-amount
-approved

credit
--------------
- id
- amount
- type
- name
```

Am I able to return all transactions cash or credit using left join I tried it but it's not giving me the correct results. I want it to get all the approved cash transactions and also get all credit records.

```
Transactions::query('transactions as t')
->leftJoin('cash as ca','ca.id', '=', 't.cash_id')
->leftJoin('credit as cr', 'cr.id', '=', 't.credit_id')
->where('ca.approved', '=', 1);
```

Comment: Did this give you any results even you hadn't called the `get()` method at the end ?

Comment: I have a get method I just forgot to place it anyway I will just use union statement thank you